# Probability distribution of X - bottles with matching caps

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

the question is:

you have n bottles in a row, (bottle#1 bottle#2 bottle#3... bottle#n) and you have their caps (every cap is different) in a box.
you pull a random cap from the box and place in on bottle1, then you pull another cap from the box and place it on bottle 2, and so on. (every bottle has one cap that matches it)

X is the number of bottles with a matching cap.
what is the distribution of X.

1. Binomial
2. Geometric
3. Hyper geometric
4. X doesn't have a distribution with a name.
5. non of the above

--
my take:
I concluded that the distribution is not binomial - because the probability of success is changing with each cap places, (it could be 0 (if the i'th cap were already placed on another bottle) or $\frac{1}{n-i}$ when i is the current cap).

It can't be Geometric because we want X successfull trials and not 1.

it's not hyper Geomtric, because there are no "Special items", every i'th trial there is just 1.

about 4. I tried calculating for n success trials with changing probability but i got stuck because some of those can be 0  , and I don't know how to procceed.

help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Pr(X=n-1)=0$ because you can't have all but $1$ matching bottle cap. The remaining probabilities are all nonzero, as you can have $x$ matching caps always by matching the first $x$ caps and then shifting the remaining caps over by $1$. In particular $Pr(X=n)=1/n!$

So just pick that the distribution has no name. Or it is possible you believe it has a name somwhere, in which case pick e.